# Improve function run-time

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, runtime

I created a function that gets a data structures and and replaces all its tuples to lists.

for example:

```
in_data = ({'name': 'Bob', 'age': 50, 'children': ('Alex', 'Justin', 'Daniel')},
           {'Name': 'Olive', 'Age': 42, 'Children': ('Rose', 'Vera', 'Karen')})

out_data = [{'name': 'Bob', 'age': 50, 'children': ['Alex', 'Justin', 'Daniel']}, 
            {'Name': 'Olive', 'Age': 42, 'Children': ['Rose', 'Vera', 'Karen']}]
```

this is the function:

```
def t2l(data):
    if type(data) in [tuple]:
        data = list(data)
    for inx, item in enumerate(data):  
        if type(data) in [dict]:
            inx, item = item, data[item]
        if type(item) in [tuple]:
            data[inx] = list(item)
            item = data[inx]
        if type(item) in (list, dict, tuple):
            data[inx] = t2l(item)
    return data
```

This function will run on millions of rows from an RDD so i want to improve it as much as i can.

Is there a way to improve the run-time like out of the box functions i can use to make this better?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to do this? You might be able to dump it to json and reload it

Comment: Side note: May I ask why you need to perform such a conversion? Is it not possible to receive the data directly as a list or to use the data directly as a tuple

Comment: when converting an RDD with a tuple to Dataframe in PySpark  I'm getting a java pointer insted of an array. once converting it to a list i get the correct data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea if its quicker or would tamper with other data you have but you can dump to json and reload it

```
import json


print(json.loads(json.dumps(in_data)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be quicker, but I am not sure if you want to check anything else other than `tuple`:

```
def t2l(data):
    for item in data:
        for key in item:
            if type(item[key]) is tuple:
                item[key] = [*item[key]]
    data = [*data]
    return data
```

Performance:

```
%%timeit
t2l(in_data*1000000)

735 ms ± 12.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
json.loads(json.dumps(in_data*1000000))

4.43 s ± 37.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```